# WF4 Custom Persistence Examples

Tags: persistence, workflow-foundation-4

I am writing my own custom persistence instance store for WF4, based on the XmlWorkflowInstanceStore found in the .NET 4 WF and WCF samples. This sample is quite simplistic and the xml is produces is quite verbose. I have issues with how some of the objects are serialized.

I have tried using Red Gate Reflector to understand the Sql implementation used, but it is quite complex and difficult to learn from. The MS documentation for this is rather limited - often giving one sentence descriptions for complex methods.

Please could you point me at other examples of WF4 persistence (or proper documentation) around on the web that are not copy and paste versions of XmlWorkflowInstanceStore? Maybe someone else on StackOverflow has written their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely correct that the docs are very much lacking here and the sample is of very limited use. I have started work on a custom instance store using the entity framework but, much like you discovered, found it slow going and am nowhere near anything I could use myself, let alone release onto CodePlex.

I am not aware of any blog posts or other information that help solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably seen this already, but I've found the code quite easy to understand: http://xhinker.com/post/WF4Xml-persistence-store.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ron Jacobs wrote an in memory persistence store for WF unit testing. Check out http://wf.codeplex.com/releases/view/73842